# Change 'resize' to 'onload' JS

Tags: javascript, resize, onload

Currently, this script only works when I adjust the window - I'd like it to work on load but do not know-how. I think this is simple but I can't figure it out.

```
      $(window).on('resize', function() {
if($(window).height() > 300) {
    $('.card').addClass('hover');
    $('.card').removeClass('no');
}else{
    $('.card').addClass('no');
    $('.card').removeClass('hover');
}
```

})

Comment: You need to replace `'resize'` with `'load'` (not 'onload')

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function and execute it onload and as a event listener of the onresize

```
function resizeHandler() {
  if ($(window).height() > 300) {
    $('.card').addClass('hover');
    $('.card').removeClass('no');
  } else {
    $('.card').addClass('no');
    $('.card').removeClass('hover');
  }
}

$(window).on('resize', resizeHandler);
$(document).ready(resizeHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also needed to adjust my code to say "height":   ($(window).width became  if ($(window).height